# Maximum recommended layer height for an Elegoo Saturn?

Tags: resin, layer-height

I have an Elegoo Saturn resin printer and I want to print out some low detail models that are about three inches on each side. I'm going to add the detail in using traditional modelling, kit-bashing and painting after the models have been printed.

In order to get a faster print I'd like to increase the layer height, what is the maximum recommended height for a print of this size?

For example, if I'm printing tanks that have little or no surface detail.

Comment: I don't have any experience with resin printers but here is some info that may be helpful. https://www.reddit.com/r/ElegooSaturn/comments/kwy1fg/testing_layer_height_with_elegoo_saturn_advice/

Comment: Hi @Kezat - You could make an answer out of that interesting link (in case the reddit thread gets deleted, as they often do), by quoting the salient points from it.

Answer (score 2):

Layer height affects the exposure time. Thicker layers mean that you need to expose longer. You would need to test and verify what works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Please ignore the vague comment above which was automatically generated by our poorly thought out new review mechanism... however, if you could expand your answer to give maybe a range of example exposure times for example thicknesses, that would be great.